# How to set string query using not equal to empty?

Tags: string

```
contact c=[select id,firstname,lastname ,email from contact where email !=''];
```

above query how to set string query.Please anybody help on this

Comment: What does it mean by **set string query**? Do you mean a dynamic query?

Comment: select id,firstname,lastname ,email from contact where email !='' this query how to get records using string query  like 'select id,firstname,lastname ,email from contact where email !='''

Answer (score 2):

I think this may solve your query.

```
String qur = 'Select Id from Contact where email != \'\'';
System.debug('**  ' + Database.query(qur));
```

Answer (score 1):

Below query can be used insted:

```
List<Contact> contactList = Database.query('select id,firstname,lastname ,email from contact where email != null');
```

Whereas to answer your question, use **Escape Sequences** as below:

```
List<Contact> contactList = Database.query('select id,firstname,lastname ,email from contact where email != \'\'');
```

Comment: @ Madhavi Bhattad thanks for qiuck reply It's working fine

Comment: I saw your all reply's perfect and i am vote for your answers